# Append the value in select box using jquery

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<select name="area" style=" background-color:none;filter:Alpha(Opacity=60);opacity:0;" id="person" data-mini="true">
    <option value="0" style="color:#FFF; font-size:20px;">Select Person</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
function deliveryperson(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mobile/product/deliveryperson',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            //$("#list").append("<option>Hi</option>");
            $("#person").empty();
            alert(hi);
            var option1 = "<option value='0'>Select person</option>";
            $("#person").append(option1);
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                if(item.name != "Ingredients"){
                    var option = '<option value="'+item.name+'">'+item.name+'</option>';
                    $("#person").append(option);
                }
            });
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        }
    });
}
```

Using this url i got the output like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => alandur2 [contact] => 1236547896 [areaname] => Alandur MKN Road [username] => alandur2 [password] => d11938279d313e5000c2dfb16db8eeb1 [delflag] => 1 [status] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => alandur3 [contact] => 9876543214 [areaname] => Alandur MKN Road [username] => alandur3 [password] => d11938279d313e5000c2dfb16db8eeb1 [delflag] => 1 [status] => 0 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => alandur4 [contact] => 9632587415 [areaname] => Alandur MKN Road [username] => alandur4 [password] => 04e4e8a85497746ce540ead2d9348f67 [delflag] => 1 [status] => 0 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 5 [name] => alandur5 [contact] => 8547321697 [areaname] => Alandur MKN Road [username] => alandur5 [password] => 39558146c0883cf8bdaacd26b549cc0b [delflag] => 1 [status] => 0 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 6 [name] => alandur1 [contact] => 9566435861 [areaname] => Alandur MKN Road [username] => alandur1 [password] => 590a60b1e1c85f9a778a4adb649b2a8c [delflag] => 1 [status] => 5 ) 
)
```

I need only name from this array.But i can't append the value.Please tell what's the error in this coding.

Comment: what does your php look like?

Comment: Maybe you could ask your PHP server person to be nicer and return Json instead of a PHP array in text form? It would sure make things easier.

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(data);`?

Comment: The function not calling

Comment: If i select the select button how to call deliveryperson function